# How to Decode The String and Fetch data from Server and show in ListView?

Tags: android

I want to fetch data from server and want to display it in ListView but string is encoded so I am not able to fetch encoded data. So how to convert and fetch it in ListView?

Feed type=`N,W,E,U {N-News,W-Wallet,E-Events,U-Update}`
URL=`"http://bridgeapi.csccloud.in/cscwork/mobile/fetch/feeds/format/json"`
Input-Parameters= `app_id=MOBI|app_key=12345|device_hash=12345|csc_id=500100100013|feed_type=W|rec_cnt=10|page_num=1|server_timestamp=2017-1-17 10:51:24|`

Data:

```
<?xml version ="1.0" encoding="utf"?>
    <xml>
    <request_data>YXBwX2lkPU1PQkl8YXBwX2tleT0xMjM0NXxkZXZpY2VfaGFzaD0xMjM0NXxjc2NfaWQ9NTAwMTAwMTAwMDEzfGZlZWRfdHlwZT1XfHJlY19jbnQ9MTB8cGFnZV9udW09MXxzZXJ2ZXJfdGltZXN0YW1wPTIwMTctMS0xNyAxMDo1MToyNHw=
    </xml>
```

Comment: This question is very unclear. Add some information so we can help you, like: how do you fetch the data from the server? What protocol are you using? What encryption is used for the data? What have you already tried? Etc.

Comment: Base 64 encoding i have applied volley like this

Comment: It appears as if you are asking three questions (Fetch data, decode data, display data in listview) in this one post. Please ask one distinct question and provide the code with which you are having problems.